# Unable to make modifications to amplifyconfiguration.dart

Tags: flutter, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, flutter-aws-amplify

**Background**
I have created a new flutter project and initialised amplify using `amplify init` then added an api using `amplify add api`

**What am I trying to do?**
I am trying to change my REST API from an `authorizationType` of `AWS_IAM` to `API_KEY` and I am following the instructions as described here: [Amplify Flutter REST API](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/authz/q/platform/flutter/#api-key)

I manually change the `amplifyconfiguration.dart` file to change the `authorizationType` from `AWS_IAM` to `API_KEY` and specify my apiKey with the API key I setup via the AWS Console. I then execute a amplify push to push my changes to the cloud.

From

```
"UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "testrestapi": {
                    "endpointType": "REST",
                    "endpoint": "https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev",
                    "region": "ap-southeast-2",
                    "authorizationType": "AWS_IAM"
                }
            }
        }
    }"
```

To

```
"UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "testrestapi": {
                    "endpointType": "REST",
                    "endpoint": "https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev",
                    "region": "ap-southeast-2",
                    "authorizationType": "API_KEY",
                    "apiKey":"<MY KEY>"                  
                }
            }
        }
    },"
```

**Whats the problem?**
After executing a amplify push command, the `amplifyconfiguration.dart` file reverts back to its original values.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a new flutter project using flutter create
2. Initialise amplify via the amplify init command
3. Add an API via the amplify add api command
4. Open the project in an editor (eg Visual Studio Code), open amplifyconfiguration.dart and change the REST API details. Hit save.
5. Execute amplify push. The amplifyconfiguration.dart file will revert back to its original state.

How can I make changes to amplifyconfiguration.dart and make the changes persist? Alternatively how can I change my REST API fom the CLI as above? I have tried amplify update api but it does not allow me to change the authorizationType. The documentation states that I can make changes to the file manually but any changes dont seem to persist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy, in the **amplify console**, go to the **data** tab and under the title (**Data modeling**) there is a gear symbol and a text that says: **GraphQL API settings**. Click and you can **change the Default authorization mode** option for the one you need. Then you update your project that you are working on.