# How to add an existing API to flutter amplify for different environments

Tags: flutter, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, flutter-aws-amplify

I'm using Amplify for auth but have my own existing REST API.
I also have different deployments of this API for my different environments `local`, `dev`, `production` etc.

The [amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/existing-resources/q/platform/flutter/) say that to do so one needs to modify the `amplifyconfiguration.json` file.

E.g.

```json
{
    "api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "[API NAME]": {
                    "endpointType": "REST",
                    "endpoint": "[API GATEWAY ENDPOINT]",
                    "region": "[REGION]",
                    "authorizationType": "[AUTHORIZATION TYPE]",
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: I haven't found any mention of this file other than in the docs so I assume they mean the `lib/amplifyconfiguration.dart` (which contains the configuration as a json string).

The existing api I wish to add has a different url for each amplify environment.

And when switching between environments amplify appears to rebuild the `amplifyconfiguration.dart` file.

So my question is:
Does anyone know how you can configure an existing resource per environment and have it update in the `lib/amplifyconfiguration.dart` as one switches environment with `amplify env checkout dev|prod|etc`?

Comment: Similar (year old and unanswered) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300802/unable-to-make-modifications-to-amplifyconfiguration-dart)